# Does NFS requires a directory with full permission in order to share with other clients?

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, nfs, nfsv4

I have set up NFS share and it is working properly with 770 or 777 permission on the directory but the minute I have the permission for the group like 760 or 750 then it stops work and I can't access the share( it says permission denied ).

when the permission is:

```
chmod 770 /public
```

then it works properly but when the permission is:

```
chmod 760 /public
```

It does not let me access the share giving me an error saying permission denied.

Comment: Does the user account you're using have the same uid/gid on each client system?

Answer (score 0):

The user account you use to access the share, needs to have the required  permissions to access it, the same way as a "normal" directory (i.e. on the local disk).

Since you *can* access it with `0770` permissions set, your user account apparently is a member of the same group as the share itself.

To put it another way: if you make some normal directory, say `/test` and set permissions to `0740` you would also only be able to access it, if you are the *owner* of `/test`. This is not a special thing inn NFS or something like that.